# Are there some best practices how to build a client library for an API?

Tags: python, api, client

I was tasked to create an API client library for our already existing API. I tried to research some ways how to approach this but couldn't find anything. Are there some best practices how to build such client library, or are there some already existing clients from which I can get some inspiration?

Comment: This question is very broad and sparse with details. It will likely attract a huge variety of answers that are all equally correct, which makes this a poor fit for this community. You've done research, which is good, but you haven't presented us with a problem to solve. Can you [edit] your question to describe your problem, what research you've done, and why that research didn't satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the presumption that the API is exposed/accessible to broader use than a private application it means it isn't used/called/accessed. A reason could be it is too complex to use it. A client library could be the solution to ease its usage.

Without any details about the API, a starting point could be creational design patterns, the way factory and builder design patterns are. Rephrased that means answering the question "what is that the client library has to solve?" gets to how the client library should be implemented.